# Oracle UTC date string insertion in a date column

Tags: sql, oracle, perl, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am getting a response from one of our API like below,

```
'createdate' => 'Sun Jan 31 04:40:15 UTC 2016'
```

I am using Oracle database to save API data and I am using Perl language to parse the API data. Before inserting the above date field into db, I did the following in my Perl to convert String to Date and it is working fine.

```
$res->{'createdate'} = strftime ('%d-%b-%y',localtime(str2time($res->{'createdate'})));
```

I have tried the same using insert query(Oracle)  like below, so I can remove the Perl conversion. It ends up with some error.

For eg:

```
insert
into device_det (id, createdate)
values (111111,TO_TIMESTAMP('Wed Aug 16 16:59:31 UTC 2017', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

This gives error as below.

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
*Cause:    Illegal year entered
*Action:   Input year in the specified range
```

Comment: Shouldn't the second arg of `TO_TIMESTAMP` be the pattern to match that data string? The `YYYY-MM-DD` is your target, right? According [to the doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions193.htm) the target is always of type `TIMESTAMP`. But then I have never used Oracle, all I do is read the docs.

Comment: Try `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('Wed Aug 16 16:59:31 UTC 2017', 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZR YYYY')`

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your attempt. First, and conceptually most important, your input string represents a timestamp WITH TIME ZONE, not a generic timestamp. Regardless of how you are going to add it to your database, what is the **data type** needed for this data? Do you need to convert it to "local" time zone, and then simply discard the time zone info? (Consider also the TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE data type though - do a Google search to find the documentation if you are not familiar with it.) You need to make this decision - or your business must make this decision - before any practical implementation. Or, alternatively, you could keep the data in TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE data type (with UTC as the time zone).

The second, as already mentioned in a Comment to your question, is that the format model doesn't match the actual structure of your input string. Your format model begins with `'YYYY'` so the input string should have the year first. But it doesn't; it has `'Wed '`. Obviously that is not going to work, even if you fix the first problem. But answering the first question is really the main point; fixing the format model is much easier.